# Find a unitary basis of the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of $n \times n$ (complex) Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

The question is on the title ($n \in \mathbb{N}^*$). To be clear, **unitary basis** here means basis consisting of (complex) [unitary matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix).

I wonder this question because recently I've read about [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices), which are all unitary and, together with the identity matrix $I_2$, make up a basis of the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of $2 \times 2$ [Hermitian matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix). There are 4 elements in that basis, suitably as the vector space has $\dim = 2 \times 2 = 4$. In the general case, this would be $n^2$.

Disclaimer: I should prove the existence of such basis first, but I haven't done it. Still I think there exists at least one $\forall n$.

Comment: See [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#A_non-Hermitian_generalization_of_Pauli_matrices) and [this post on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/326767/34894).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The basis is very elegant! However, it's not Hermitian (though it spans Hermitian matrices). Is there a way to change this?

Comment: The [Gell-Mann matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Generalized_Gell-Mann_matrices_(Hermitian)) from that same wiki page are Hermitian, but they're not generally unitary.

Comment: It’s notable that when $n$ is odd, there are no trace-zero unitary and Hermitian matrices

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So we have 2 bases, one is unitary but not Hermitian, one is traceless Hermitian but not generally unitary (definitely not for odd $n$). Still, the desired basis hasn't been reached yet. Also, for $n = 2^k$, we can tensor product to create the desired basis.